# Window.opener alternative when not opening a new window

Tags: javascript, browser

Small prob i'm using the following line of code

```
customerName = window.opener.form2.custName.value;
```

The problem is that I'm no longer opening the page in a new window, I'm opening it in the same window and thus replacing the older page.

Is there anyway for me to get the same information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as a paratemer in the query string to the new page.

If you would open the new page as, say: `<a href="newPage.html">...`, pass the details as `<a href="newPage.html?custName="+document.form2.custName.value>`

As an alternative you can use cookies to store the data from page 1 before you navigate away and retrieve it in page 2.

Comment: how would i then set the customerName var in the new page to be equal to the parameter passed in the query string?

Comment: You need to parse the query string. See http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/AdamAnderson/07-12-17/Parse_a_Query_String_in_JavaScript.aspx

Comment: Remember, the query string will snow up in the URL, and this is perhaps what you want. If not, use cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Great answer, does exactly what i need!

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't opening a new window, window.opener won't be available.

You could try passing the value of custName on the query string e.g. http://example.com/somepage.htm?custName=`<yourValueHere>`.

Its relatively easy to get query string values in javascript, try using http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object for example.

Otherwise, set a cookie and retrieve its value on the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value / values you want on to the new page in some way. Some pointers:

- Use a cookie to store the value in one page, then retrieve it in the next.
- Pass it on as a parameter in the URL, or by submitting a form to the new page.
- Store it in session, then retrieve it.

Of course, you may also wish to consider the nature of the data. If it is sensitive, you should use the session or form alternatives to ensure that info is not viewable from the outside (in a cookie, or in the browser's URL, for instance).